# C++: Find Installation Directory of MS PowerPoint Viewer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I would like to **call MS PowerPoint Viewer executable(PPTVIEW.exe) from within my C++ application.**

I do not wish to ask the user, where MS PowerPoint viewer is installed. I believe, it is not professional and relies on user making appropriate input. Instead, I would like to be able to identify the location of the installation directory on my own.

For example, the default location of MS PowerPoint Viewer 2007 is the following:

- **c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\PPTVIEW.exe**

This of course does not have to be always true, especially different versions (2003, 2007, 2010) have have different locations.

Would you advise, please, **where to get the correct path, and even better, to be able to identify, if MS PowerPoint viewer is not installed at all?**

There must be something in the registry, but which key is the correct one?

I use:

- Non Managed C++
- Needs to be compatible with WinXP
- Should be compatible with bot 32 and 64 bit OS
- Should be able to identify location of Powerpoint Viewer of all the versions after 2003(including.)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need the location of the viewer application or do you rather want to open a document that is associated with the viewer. If the latter is what you ultimately want to achieve you can use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) which does all the heavy-lifting for you. Plus it respects the user setting which application to launch for a particular file type.

Comment: @Tim, hello and thanks for your input. I am controlling PowerPoint viewer through command line with various parameters. I need to be able to kill the PowerPoint Viewer process on demand, and need to be able to play list of files, or single file. As needed. For those and more reasons, I need to have access to executable, so I can use PowerPoint Viewer command line parameters. Thanks for your input, again.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution so far i found is searching for the appropriate path in registry by reading the following registry key:

- **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\pptview.exe**

The key above gives me location to where PowerPoint Viewer is installed. However, I have no clue whether this key is present in every workstation where PowerPoint Viewer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you rephrase the question as "I would like to display a powerpoint in slideshow mode from within my C++ application." then it would be easy to achive this by querying the registered file handler and using the applicable COM object.

The following registry key will be present if there is a registered extension handler:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\
```